# Defining multiple constant variables in clojure

Tags: variables, clojure, constants

I'm trying to define several constant variables in clojure. Is there a way to define all of them in one def statement? Or must I define each one separately?

In any programming language (C++ Java) you may expect to be able to do the following

```
    const int x, y, z;
    x = y = z = 0;
```

However, in clojure I'm having trouble doing something similar with the def declaration. I've tried something based off of the 'let' syntax:

```
    (def ^:const [x 2 y 3 z 8])
```

and something like

```
    (def ^:const x 2 y 3 z 8)
```

but none of these work. Must I separately define each variable?

Comment: note that `^:const` in clojure does not do what `const` does in other languages, in particular vars are always mutable and the `^:const` metadata tells the compiler it can inline a primitive value but does not prevent you from erroneously changing it anyway

Comment: Oh. Well, is there a way to create a final immutable value in clojure??

Comment: Sure, we have immutable data structures for example. But vars are a mutable container.

Comment: I'd like to add that, while vars *are* mutable, you generally don't go around changing their (root) values programmatically, except sometimes in dynamic development.

Comment: Your C/C++ is wrong. The nearest I can get past the compiler is ` const int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;`, which separately defines each variable.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a separate Var for `x`, `y`, and `z`, you must define each one separately:

```
(def x 2)
(def y 3)
(def z 8)
```

You could easily write a macro to define multiple constants at once if this is too cumbersome:

```
(defmacro defs
  [& bindings]
  {:pre [(even? (count bindings))]}
  `(do
     ~@(for [[sym init] (partition 2 bindings)]
         `(def ~sym ~init))))

(defs x 2 y 3 z 8)
```

If these three constants are related, though, you could instead define a map with an entry for each number:

```
(def m {:x 2, :y 3, :z 8})
```

Depending on your use case, you may even find it valuable to define them as a vector instead:

```
(def v [2 3 8])
```